# How to use composer with a non-packagist github project containing a packages.json

Tags: composer-php, momentjs, packagist, satis

I want to put https://github.com/timrwood/moment into my composer.json for easy maintenance.

It's not an official packagist project (of course, as it's not PHP), but it contains a `packages.json` for nodejs. Can I use this in my `composer.json`?

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
{
    "repositories": {
        "timrwood/moment": {
           "type": "git",
           "url": "git://github.com/timrwood/moment.git"
        }
    }
}
```

It throws an error message saying *"No valid composer.json was found in any branch or tag of git://github.com/timrwood/moment.git, could not load a package from it."*

And it is lacking the version string to define the version I want to use...

Can anyone help here?

Or shouldn't I use composer here at all cause I'm mixing JS and PHP?

Comment: Hav you looked into Satis? https://github.com/composer/satis and http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md

Comment: Haven't tried it yet, thanks for the hint! I'll give it a try.

Comment: Current composer version allows adding a `composer.json` by hand: http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#repositories

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Composer only manages composer packages. It does not know how to parse a `package.json` file. There are different approaches to this problem. Composer may be able to deal with frontend dependencies in the future.

For the time being I'd recommend using a separate dependency manager for your JavaScript dependencies. Either NPM or something like [jam](http://jamjs.org/) or [ender](http://ender.no.de/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried jam, but had the problem that the repositories of jam had an old version of my needed library. So I ended up using [Bower](https://github.com/twitter/bower).

Answer (score 0):

Check out composer plugin to handle components via `bower`, `nodejs` and `git` repositories: [fxpio/composer-asset-plugin](https://github.com/francoispluchino/composer-asset-plugin).